# ASP.NET Core Web API : how to view image from server url with Apikey middleware restriction

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

ASP.NET Core 6 Web API: when I want to see with browser images from my server, I got error for `Apikey` middleware then.

> Api Key was not provided

Provide by middleware I put for `Apikey`.

This is the code of my middleware:

```
public class ApiKeyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private const string APIKEY = "XApiKey";

    public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEY, out var extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Api Key was not provided ");
            return;
        }

        var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEY);

        if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized client");
            return;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And the code of `Program.cs` :

```
app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),@"Upload")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Upload")
            });
```

I tried to get my image from server to my browser to make it available in my web application but I cannot view it due to Apikey restriction

Comment: I use Postman to test your code and everything goes well, From the error message `Api Key was not provided` I think you may not add request header correctly,  Can you provide the code about how you send request to this web api?